# Why I need to click 2 times on button to change the location

Tags: angularjs

I want to change current url to different page on click of a button. But the problem is I need to click the button 2 times then it changes the location.

here is my code

```
function CreateUserController($scope, $location) {
    $scope.submitForm = function(angObj) {
        if(angObj.$valid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/users/createUserNew",
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                data: $("#createUserForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('passed');
                    $location.path("/users");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Why I need to click 2 times the button to change the location?

```
<button ng-click="submitForm(userForm)" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ng-class="{'disabled' : userForm.$invalid}" class="btn btn-primary">        
    <span class="btn-title">Create New User</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Either angObj is not valid on your first click but is valid on your second or it's the fact that the ajax call is asynchronous.

Comment: angObj is valid. As I can see the console message passed on first click. And on the second click the url is changed and again passed in console.

Comment: Did you try to wrap the call to $location.path with $apply ? e.g. $rootScope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/users"); });

Comment: $rootScope is not defined

Comment: Add it as a parameter of your controller...

Comment: $scope.$apply() works and now it is redirecting...

Comment: Can you please put the code in answer? with little explanation why needs to apply? I will mark it as answer

Comment: btw why are you using jQuery instead of $http service to make an ajax request? that's why you have to use $apply, because you use jquery's ajax method angular is not aware that something could change and have to invoke digest loop which will perform dirty checking.

Comment: how to convert it to its $http equivalent?

Comment: It'll look like this

`function CreateUserController($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.submitForm = function(angObj) {
        if(angObj.$valid) {
            $http.post("/users/createUserNew", $scope.newUser
              .success(function (data) {
                    console.log('passed');
                    $location.path("/users");
              })
              .error(function (data) {
              });
        }
    }
}`
and in your html you should use binding between form fields and fields on $scope.newUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the view is simply not updated.

You could wrap the call to $location.path with $apply to force the refresh.

For example:

```
$scope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/users"); });
```

For more details on when use $apply, you can read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29).

Comment: If you use `$http` instead of `$.ajax` it will call `$apply` automatically.

Comment: still not feeling comfortable with $http :S